# Trying to find the most recent date where a status field has changed in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that shows a full history of location ID's (LOCN_ID), which includes an ACTIVE_STATUS field showing A for active, or I for inactive. Each time a location's active status changes, a new record is created with a new OP_DATE. However, any time the EXTERNALLY_VISIBLE field in the table gets changed, another record with a new OP_DATE is also created.

[Here is an example of this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9AqW.png)

For each LOCN_ID in the table, I need to be able to find the most recent OP_DATE that the ACTIVE_STATUS field changed (to either I or A). I don't care about when the EXTERNALLY_VISIBLE field changed. For the LOCN_ID shown in the example, the result should be:

```
    OP_DATE       LOCN_ID   ACTIVE_STATUS
  12/9/11 7:34     558732         I
```

There are also some cases where a LOCN_ID's active status will have never changed, in which case the result should be the oldest OP_DATE for that LOCN_ID.

How would I be able to write a query in Oracle SQL to show this desired output for each LOCN_ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to handle both situations, when there is a row where status changed and when it's absent. `Lag()` is obvious as it is designed to find previous values. Optional is older, slower self-join. Also we need `row_number()`, because you have complicated conditional ordering. In `row_number` as first part we need descending order, then ascending in case there were no status changes. It can be done like here:

```
select op_date, locn_id, active_status
  from (
    select a.*, row_number() 
                over (partition by locn_id 
                      order by case when active_status <> las then sysdate-op_date end, 
                               op_date) as rn
      from (select t.*, lag(active_status) over (partition by locn_id order by op_date) las 
              from t) a) 
  where rn = 1
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=651d376e234f3da170c56ecfb66ed580)</sup>**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by locn_id order by op_date desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(active_status) over (partition by locn_id order by op_date) as prev_active_status
            from t
           ) t
       where prev_active_status <> active_status
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This returns 4/6/13 as the OP_DATE because the EXTERNALLY_VISIBLE field changed from N to Y on that date, and ACTIVE_STATUS remained I. I need the result to show 12/9/11 because that's the most recent date where the ACTIVE_STATUS changed (in this case from A to I).

Comment: @JNegoda . . .  I see.  I fixed the answer to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the following query for you using LEFT JOIN:

```
-- SAMPLE DATA
WITH DATAA (OP_DATE, LOCN_ID, ACTIVE_STATUS, EXTERNALLY_VISIBLE)
AS
(
SELECT TO_DATE('04/06/2013 2:31','MM/DD/RRRR HH24:MI'), 558732, 'I', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('12/09/2011 7:34','MM/DD/RRRR HH24:MI'), 558732, 'I', 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('10/02/2011 3:05','MM/DD/RRRR HH24:MI'), 558732, 'A', 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('10/02/2011 2:59','MM/DD/RRRR HH24:MI'), 558732, 'I', 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('10/02/2011 3:00','MM/DD/RRRR HH24:MI'), 558732, 'I', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('04/09/2011 2:18','MM/DD/RRRR HH24:MI'), 558732, 'A', 'Y' FROM DUAL
),
-- ACTUAL QUERY STARTS FROM HERE
CTE(OP_DATE, LOCN_ID, ACTIVE_STATUS, EXTERNALLY_VISIBLE, RN) AS (
    SELECT
        D.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY LOCN_ID
            ORDER BY
                OP_DATE
        ) AS RN
    FROM
        DATAA D
)
SELECT
    OP_DATE,
    LOCN_ID,
    ACTIVE_STATUS
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            A.OP_DATE,
            A.LOCN_ID,
            A.ACTIVE_STATUS,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                PARTITION BY A.LOCN_ID
                ORDER BY
                    A.OP_DATE DESC
            ) AS RN
        FROM
            CTE A
            LEFT JOIN CTE B ON ( A.RN = B.RN + 1 )
        WHERE
            ( A.ACTIVE_STATUS <> B.ACTIVE_STATUS
              OR B.ACTIVE_STATUS IS NULL )
    )
WHERE
    RN = 1;
```

**-- Output --**

```
OP_DATE                LOCN_ID A
------------------- ---------- -
09-12-2011 07:34:00     558732 I
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4cf82ef1b0b2774431d5e387e9275ca3)

Cheers!!